# HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field id's type BINARY in parquet is incompatible with type int defined in table schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I made a table in athena defining data types of each column. now I can't open the table because `HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field id's type BINARY in parquet is incompatible with type int defined in table schema.`
this field is an integer type so where did the binary come from?

Comment: Can you try changing the table column to string and query again?

Comment: Please provide the create table statement and some example data.